# Borland C++ Builder: Some UI-Events not available anymore?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe, c++builder-5

I'm currently porting old code from Borland C++ Builder 5 to C++ Builder XE (the newest version). There seem to be a lot of properties and some events that are not anymore supported in XE. Most of them have been set to default values anyway, so it was no problem to remove them. Now, however, I have encountered the following problem: The event OnKeyUp is not available for TPanels anymore! Why is that? How can I fix this? And how did an OnKeyUp event on a TPanel work anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OnKeyUp` event still exists.  It is protected in `TControl`, as it always has been.  Descendants choose whether to promote it to public/published access. That has not changed. `TPanel` did not promote any of the `OnKey...` events in BCB5 (or any other version), so I don't know whay you could have been using before.